# Clear pinned pages in OrientDB 2.2.6

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm running OrientDB 2.2.6 on Windows 7 (64 bit) and I keep getting the following warning when I run a TestNG test in Java 8.

```
2016-10-05 10:46:10:888 WARNI {db=orientSystemDb} Maximum amount of pinned pages is 
  reached, given page OReadCacheEntry{fileId=7136553380276606136, pageIndex=0,
  dataPointer=OCachePointer{referrersCount=1, usagesCount=0}, dirty=false, usagesCount=1} 
  will not be marked as pinned which may lead to performance degradation. You may consider
  to increase percent of pined pages by changing of property storage.diskCache.pinnedPages
  [O2QCache]
```

I'd prefer not to increase the percent of pinnedPages right now since memory usage will probably be limited. What I would like to do is clear the pages that have been pinned when the database has started and see if that resolves the issue.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<orient-server>
<handlers>
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.handler.OGraphServerHandler">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="50" name="graph.pool.max"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="${distributed}" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/default-distributed-db-config.json" name="configuration.db.default"/>
            <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/hazelcast.xml" name="configuration.hazelcast"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OJMXPlugin">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="true" name="profilerManaged"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="false" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/automatic-backup.json" name="config"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
    <handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OServerSideScriptInterpreter">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
            <parameter value="SQL" name="allowedLanguages"/>
        </parameters>
    </handler>
</handlers>
<network>
    <protocols>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
        <protocol name="http" implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb"/>
    </protocols>
    <listeners>
        <listener protocol="binary" socket="default" port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
        <listener protocol="http" port-range="2480-2485" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
            <commands>
                <command implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.command.get.OServerCommandGetStaticContent" pattern="GET|www GET|studio/ GET| GET|*.htm GET|*.html GET|*.xml GET|*.jpeg GET|*.jpg GET|*.png GET|*.gif GET|*.js GET|*.css GET|*.swf GET|*.ico GET|*.txt GET|*.otf GET|*.pjs GET|*.svg">
                    <parameters>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\nPragma: no-cache" name="http.cache:*.htm *.html"/>
                        <entry value="Cache-Control: max-age=120" name="http.cache:default"/>
                    </parameters>
                </command>
            </commands>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</network>
<users>
    <user resources="*" password="root" name="root"/>
    <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="guest" name="guest"/>
</users>
<properties>
    <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
    <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
    <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
    <!-- Avoid updating versions when created or deleting edges -->
    <entry value="-1" name="ridBag.embeddedToSbtreeBonsaiThreshold"/>
    </properties>
</orient-server>
```

Here is the code for creating edges:

```
private int connectToAllOtherVertices(OrientBaseGraph oGraph, OrientVertex oVertex)
{
  int numConnections = 0;

  for(Vertex v : oGraph.getVertices())
  {
    if(v.equals(oVertex))
    {
      // skip it
      continue;
    }

    oVertex.addEdge(String.format("connection%s", numConnections), v);
    numConnections++;
  }

  return numConnections;
}
```

I'm able to create the edges but I keep getting the above warnings. How can I clear the pinned pages before running my tests?

Answer (score 0):

Pinned pages is special area of disk cache which unloaded from RAM only when OrientDB storage is closed. So you may try using `closeStorage` method. See [javadoc](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/storage/cache/local/twoq/O2QCache.html#closeStorage-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.cache.OWriteCache-).